# Sorting a List based on element values

Tags: c#

```
Product : {
   price :10,
   tax:2
}
```

Above code is for a single product. I have a list of products, with various Product price and tax. I need a way to sort this list in descending order in relation to the total price (Which should take into account the total price which will be price+tax). The Below list of products should have the order where the first element should have the highest price + tax.

```
Products [
    Product : {
       price :15,
       tax:2
   }  ,
   Product : {
        price :1,
       tax:32
   }  
 ,
   Product : {
        price :2,
       tax:2
   }  




]
```

Comment: Did you try anything so far or do you ask us to do your job? There are dozens of questions like "how to sort a list based on a property".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use of Linq `OrderByDescending()` to get the highest values first

`Products = Products.OrderByDescending(x => x.price + x.tax).ToList();`